# Can we change the comment-flag system on The Heap chatroom?

Tags: discussion, chat

Yesterday (April 1st, April Fools Day notwithstanding) we had some high-ranking members of DBA.SE banned from chat by moderators/10k users from other sites that did not take an appropriate amount of time to evaluate the situation.  The Heap is a place where many 10k+ users hang out and talk about many subjects, some which may seem to outsiders as offensive.  Much along the lines of what happens in the SO C++ room - we banter about and have a bit of fun, occasionally poking fun at each other.

From the transcript of the room (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/179/2013/4/2) it appears we need to self-moderate the room, perhaps only allowing outside mods/10k users to delete/ban if there are no DBA.SE mods/10k+ users present.

Comment: +1 for common sense.

Comment: I'm not an old time user of the Heap, but an oldie of DBA.SE. I, as Max said it, think that you shouldn't really shut the cowboys, even if they don't wear a tie daily.. Talking to naughty servers daily isn't really a poetry lesson. So please don't ban anyone for just dropping the F bomb or some other gentlemen's locker chat. Thank you!

Comment: re: "gentlemen's locker chat" keep in mind we're not "an old boys club" so ... I appreciate the metaphor, just find it tired and dated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just to close the loop: an announcement was made to the moderator team by one of the DBA mods requesting that other moderators defer flags from The Heap to DBA mods and top users only.

Unfortunately, your specific feature request (to dramatically alter the chat-flag system for site-specific chatrooms) is going to be [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). However, generally, mods do their best to respect the "autonomy" of individual rooms. I'll be keeping an eye on the situation; if you all see this occur again, bringing it to meta (that is, ***bringing it up here***) is absolutely the correct thing to do.